# Fully qualified path for a folder

Tags: windows, vb6, windows-10, junction, fso

Using this code

```
Dim fo As Scripting.Folder
Set fo = fso.GetFolder(m_sFolder)

Dim nSubfolder As Scripting.Folder

For Each nSubfolder In fo.SubFolders

    Debug.Print "Folder " & fo.Path & " has subfolder " & nSubfolder 

Next
```

... I get the folder name "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Eigene Bilder"

This folder doesn't exist and seems to be a JUNCTION.

How can I get the fully qualified name for this folder?

Comment: I need to get the real path of that folder.

Comment: ***>> real path*** What is your use case? In every instance I've come across, there's no difference in operation. You get the same contents, etc whether you get there directly or via the junction.

Comment: When you set fso = fso.GetFolder("C:\MyUser\Documents"), you will get the subfolders "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Pictures" and "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Videos", but these folders don't exists. I need to show the user the subfolders, but when he selects one of these, the directory is empty. This is because the folder doesn't really exist. That is why I was looking for a way to get the absolute path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FSO returns non-existing subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41835870/fso-returns-non-existing-subfolders)